# Jssor banner slider caption height

Tags: slider, height, jssor, caption

I'm having trouble determining how to increase the height of the caption at the bottom of the sliders in the following example:
http://www.jssor.com/demos/banner-slider.html

Don't need the text/font increased, just the size of the div at the bottom that contains the text.  Thought I'd increase the height from 50 to 100 as I did below but that didn't change anything....any ideas?  Thanks!:

```
`<div u="caption" t="MCLIP|B" style="position: absolute; top: 250px; 
      left: 0px; width: 600px; height: 100px;">

      <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px;
      height: 100px; background-color: Black; opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha
      (opacity=50);">
      </div>

      <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; 
      width: 600px; height: 100px; color: White; font-size: 16px; 
      font-weight: bold; line-height: 100px; text-align: center;">
      Simple Caption Definition: &lt;div u="caption"   
      t="MCLIP|B" ...&gt;&lt;div/&gt;
      </div>

</div>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change `top` to 200px or less. That's to say,

Replace

```
top: 250px;
```

with

```
top: 200px;
```